# How can I get a simple pop up with information after I click on an image with html and css

Tags: html, css

just trying to figure out how to get a simple pop up to appear when clicking on a product image using HTML and CSS.

```
<div class="d-flex shop-card ">
        <img
          class="card-img shop-card"
          src="images/shirt.png"
          alt="shirt"
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: You just try this,  https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-make-a-pure-css-popup

Comment: How about you post the CSS as well? Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show/hide an element when clicking on it without using javascript but CSS only, the best approach to achieve that and yet do your best to fulfill accessibility requirements, is to use an hidden checkbox that will hold the visibility state of the tooltip that will be triggered when clicking on the corresponding label element bound to it through the `for` attribute.

This demo I shared here follows the pattern:

- A checkbox input before anything else, with a unique id `popover#n`
- A label element including the picture you need to have a tooltip bound to, with  the class `haspopover` and the `for` attribute pointing to the above checkbox
- Such label should contain a span with the class `tooltip`

I show an example with two different images each one having its own tooltip to better show the strategy:

```css
/*gives size to the img since it's pointing to a bogus src*/
.haspopover img{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

/*style for the label container (including the picture inside)*/
.haspopover {
  position: relative;  
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*style for the checkbox holding the state of tooltip visibility*/
.popoverstatus{
  display: none;
}

/*style to show the tooltip when the checkbox is checked*/
.popoverstatus:checked + .haspopover > .tooltip  {
  display: block;
}

/*style for the tooltip frame (hidden by default)*/
.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;  
  top: -5px;
  left: calc(100% + 10px);          
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: .6;
  z-index: 1000;
}

/*style for the tooltip content*/
.tooltip {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
}

/*style for the arrow element*/
.tooltip::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid black;
  left: -8px;
  top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="popover1" class="popoverstatus">
<label for="popover1" class="haspopover">
  <img src="//bogus1.jpg">  
  <span class="tooltip">This is the tooltip for the picture1 that you can style arbitrarily!</span>
</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="popover2" class="popoverstatus">
<label for="popover2" class="haspopover">
  <img src="//bogus2.jpg">  
  <span class="tooltip">This is the tooltip for the picture2 that you can style arbitrarily!</span>
</label>
```